# Output for DSPPGMREF is incorrect for some SQL objects

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I am using DB2 i for writing SQL functions and procedures. CTE's (Common Table Expressions) are also used inside the body of these functions and procedures.

These SQL members are converted into objects using RUNSQLSTM command.

But if I am running DSPPGMREF on these objects to see program references, it is showing CTE as referred file whereas it is not an actual file.

Body of my function is as:

BEGIN
WITH SAMCTE AS
   (SELECT COL1 FROM TABL1)
  SELECT COL1 INTO ABC FROM SAMCTE;
RETURN ABC;
END;

Here actual file involved in TABL1, but DSPPGMREF is showing TABL1 and SAMCTE both as FILES, which is incorrect.

I have few sources from client in which also CTE is used but on their objects CTE are not shown as file. I am not getting what is wrong in my example.

Comment: I think CTE (common table expression) means that in the background a temporary file is created based on your expression.  You might also want to add in an example of one where the CTE is *not* being shown as a file.  The SQL optimizer might choose to store the internal expression differently in some cases.

Comment: do the "other sources" also use the files without CTE?

Comment: @danny117, No , files are used in CTE and CTEs are referred in query.

Answer (score 1):

When creating object for procedure and function using RUNSQLSTM make sure all the File/Table objects which are used in the Procedure and function are in library list or qualified.

If these are not in library list then DSPPGMREF will report some incorrect FILE references as in this case CTEs are reported as referred file.